# Mongo DB REST Option

Tags: rest, mongodb

I know that one of the biggest differences between CouchDB and MongoDB is that Couch uses a REST interface. I've installed Mongo without any other libraries, and the mongod service provides a `--rest` command-line option.

Does the MongoDB REST interface do the same thing as CouchDB's? If not then what's it for?

Comment: This question looks incomplete. Please edit it.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

MongoDB does not use a REST interface for communications.

You will need to install a specific driver for you language. Just as you would for MySQL or SQL Server or most other databases.

The list of drivers [are here](http://www.mongodb.org/display/DOCS/Drivers).

The `--rest` option allows for you to run some basic queries and monitoring against the `mongod` process. It is **not** a full REST API.

Answer (score 2):

If you're interested in a REST API interface for MongoDB then check out the [Sleepy.Mongoose](http://www.snailinaturtleneck.com/blog/2010/02/22/sleepy-mongoose-a-mongodb-rest-interface/) project.

Answer (score 0):

Reason for this is that you started the database without the --rest option. To do this you can start the database from your MongoDB bin directory like "./mongod --rest".